# Button #1 can be clicked on load, then Button #2 needs to be clicked twice. Button #1 then also needs to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

There are two buttons on the website I'm creating. They are used to move a slideshow-type form. One moves the 'slideshow' forward, and the other moves it back.

Upon loading the webpage, you can click the 'Next' button successfully once to move the slideshow in the chosen direction. You can click the 'Next' button as many times as you want until you reach the end. However, switching to the 'Back' requires you to click twice before the action is carried out. You can now click the 'Back' button once to carry out the action. Clicking the 'Next' button now requires you to click twice, just like the 'Back' button was before.

HTML:

```
<div id="signupFormButtonWrapper">
    <button id="signupFormBack" class="button">Back</button>
    <button id="signupFormNext" class="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var currentScreen = 1;
    $('#signupFormNext').click(function() {
        console.log('Moving screen forwards');
        if (currentScreen < $('.signupSection').length) {
            $('#signupInfo').css('margin-left',currentScreen*(-100/$('.signupSection').length)+'%');
            currentScreen++;
        } else {
            console.log('Can\'t move');
        }
    });
    $('#signupFormBack').click(function() {
        console.log('Moving screen backwards');
        if (currentScreen >= 1) {
            currentScreen--;
            $('#signupInfo').css('margin-left',currentScreen*(-100/$('.signupSection').length)+'%');
        } else {
            console.log('Can\'t move');
        }
    });
});
```

Do excuse the `console.log` statements, they are for debugging purposes.
If it helps, when the buttons are clicked, the console does log 'Moving screen forwards' or 'Moving screen backwards', whether or not an action is carried out.
If you need more code, just ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post more of the html? as you mentioned the clicking logic on its own works (logging the moving screen stuff) but something else must be going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to increment current screen after you move, but decrement current screen before you move the screen. So let's work through the logic (state tracks the currentScreen variable (1 on start) and the slide image (0 on start))

```
STATE: currentScreen = 1, slide-image = 0
ACTION: Next button pressed
WHAT HAPPENS:
    slide-image -> 1
    currentScreen -> 2

STATE: currentScreen = 2, slide-image = 1
ACTION: Next button pressed
WHAT HAPPENS:
    slide-image -> 2
    currentScreen -> 3
```

So that works fine, now what happens when we press back

```
STATE: currentScreen = 3, slide-image = 2
ACTION: Prev button pressed
WHAT HAPPENS:
    currentScreen -> 2
    slide-image -> 2

STATE: currentScreen = 2, slide-image = 2
ACTION: Prev button pressed
WHAT HAPPENS:
    currentScreen -> 1
    slide-image -> 1
```

Here you can see, because you decrement before you set, there's a lag. The same thing happens again when you switch direction. To fix this problem start the counter at 0 and then decrement/increment before you set the image each way. eg:

```
$(function() {
     var currentScreen = 0; // start at 0
     $('#signupFormNext').click(function() {
         console.log('Moving screen forwards');
         if (currentScreen < $('.signupSection').length) {
             currentScreen++; // increment before you set css
             $('#signupInfo').css('margin-left',currentScreen*(-100/$('.signupSection').length)+'%');
        } else {
            console.log('Can\'t move');
        }
    });
    $('#signupFormBack').click(function() {
        console.log('Moving screen backwards');
        if (currentScreen >= 1) {
            currentScreen--;
            $('#signupInfo').css('margin-left',currentScreen*(-100/$('.signupSection').length)+'%');
        } else {
            console.log('Can\'t move');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Despite someone getting to the answer before you, you have provided suitable edits and a good explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, there's something wrong with the logic. Every time when you click the next button, the old value of currentScreen is used to calculate the left margin.

For example, you are on screen 4 moving to screen 5, 4 will be used for the calculation and then currentScreen will be updated to 5.

If you click back at this point, the currentScreen will be decremented from 5 to 4, and 4 will be used for the calculation again, which will result in the same value as previously calculated when clicking the next button (therefore no change). Hence, requiring you to click two times before the value of currentScreen gets decremented to 3.

Right and now after clicking the back button 2 times, currentScreen is 3, clicking the next button will cause 3 to be used for the calculation and the value for the margin left will be the same as the previous value. Therefore, requiring you 2 clicks before you see the screen move to the next slide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you logic has an issue.

See the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q8pby5cL/1/

I abstracted the movement into a function.  I replaced the check on the `.signupSection` with a hardcoded value for testing.